# How to remove horizontal scroll using tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I don't know for what reason, but I have horizontal scrolling, but according to the styles, everything seems to be correct.
I noticed that if I reduce the screen size, for example to 50%, when the "home" component fits completely on the screen, then the vertical and horizontal scrolling disappears.
I also added other components instead of "home" - everything is similar. So the problem is somewhere in this code, please help.
Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Home,
} from "../components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getAllProducts } from "../api";
import { setAllProducts } from "../context/actions/productActions";

const Main = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const isCart = useSelector((state) => state.isCart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!products) {
      getAllProducts().then((data) => {
        dispatch(setAllProducts(data));
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <main className="w-[100%] min-h-screen flex items-center justify-start flex-col bg-primary">
      <Header />
      <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col items-start justify-center mt-40 px-6 md:px-24 2xl:px-96 gap-12 pb-8">
        <Home />
      </div>

      {isCart && <Cart />}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

*home*:

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Delivery, HeroBg } from "../assets";
import { buttonClick, straggerFadeInOut } from "../animations";
import { foodInfo } from "../utils/styles";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="w-full grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4"
      id="home"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-start items-start gap-6">
        <div className="px-4 py-1 flex items-center justify-center gap-2 bg-orange-100 rounded-full">
          <p className="text-lg font-semibold text-orange-500">Free Delivery</p>
          <div className="w-10 h-10 flex items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-primary shadow-md">
            <img
              src={Delivery}
              alt=""
              className="w-full h-full object-contain"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p className="text-[40px] text-headingColor md:text-[72px] font-sans font-extrabold tracking-wider">
          The Fastest Delivery in{" "}
          <span className="text-orange-600">Your City</span>
        </p>
        <p className="text-textColor text-lg">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam vitae
          totam eveniet eligendi mollitia. Voluptates blanditiis, tenetur magnam
          natus nulla distinctio. Fuga iure odit voluptas vero aliquam quaerat
          incidunt harum.
        </p>
        <motion.button
          {...buttonClick}
          className="bg-gradient-to-bl from-orange-400 to-orange-600 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-black text-base font-semibold"
        >
          Order Now
        </motion.button>
      </div>
      <div className="py-2 flex-1 flex items-center justify-end relative">
        <img
          src={HeroBg}
          alt=""
          className="absolute top-0 right-0 md:-right-12 w-full h-420 md:w-auto md:h-650"
        />
        <div className="w-full md:w-460 ml-0 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-4 gap-y-14">
          {foodInfo &&
            foodInfo.map((data, i) => (
              <motion.div
                key={i}
                {...straggerFadeInOut(i)}
                className="w-32 h-36 md:h-auto md:w-190 p-4 bg-lightOverlay backdrop-blur-md rounded-3xl flex flex-col items-center justify-center drop-shadow-lg"
              >
                <img
                  src={data.imageURL}
                  alt=""
                  className="w-12 h-12 md:w-32 md:h-32 md:-mt-16 object-contain"
                />
                <p className="text-sm lg:text-xl font-semibold text-textColor">
                  {data.product_name.slice(0, 14)}
                </p>
                <p className="text-[12px] text-center md:text-base text-lighttextGray font-semibold capitalize">
                  {data.product_category}
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm font-semibold text-headingColor">
                  <span className="text-xs text-red-600">$</span>{" "}
                  {data.product_price}
                </p>
              </motion.div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Scale 90% of screen:
[image]

Scale 50% of screen:
[image]

Comment: can you provide the URL to the page? Or is it not live yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not alive yet?

Comment: did you try to use the overflow-hidden class on your main component, or on the div wrapping your Home component?

Comment: Yes, but no matter how it sounds, it doesn't work, unfortunately(